# Powershell add text to cvs file

Tags: powershell

I have a cvs file with title/column `channelrows` and text/value `play` and `work`. I have to add `hard`.
So that it becomes `work hard` and `play hard`.
How can i do this?

My Code

```
$channelrows = Import-Csv "D:\Powershell_Project_2\newchannels.csv"
$channelrows | ForEach-Object { $TheOldInput = $_.channelrows ; [PSCustomObject]@{channelrows = "$TheOldInput Hard"}}
```

Output

```
channelrows
-----------
  Hard     
  Hard
```

**what i need is this**

```
channelrows
-----------
  Work Hard     
  PLay Hard
```

Comment: Is column `channelrows` the only column in the csv? Please show us the first 3 or 4 lines if that is not the case

Comment: `channelrows` is the only one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the only column in the CSV file is 'channelrows', this wil be as easy as:

```
$channelrows = Import-Csv -Path "D:\Powershell_Project_2\newchannels.csv" | 
               Select-Object @{Name = 'channelrows'; Expression = {'{0} hard' -f $_.channelrows}}
# output on screen
$channelrows

# output to new CSV file
$channelrows | Export-Csv -Path "D:\Powershell_Project_2\updatedchannels.csv"
```

If there are more columns in the file, you can use this:

```
$channelrows = Import-Csv -Path "D:\Powershell_Project_2\newchannels.csv" | 
               Select-Object *, @{Name = 'channelrows'; Expression = {'{0} hard' -f $_.channelrows}} -ExcludeProperty channelrows

# output on screen
$channelrows

# output to new CSV file
$channelrows | Export-Csv -Path "D:\Powershell_Project_2\updatedchannels.csv"
```

---

If your input csv file looks like

```
channelrows
work
play
```

Then the output will be:

```
channelrows
-----------
work hard  
play hard
```

Comment: @KingVince I was going to say 'You're welcome', but you unaccepted the answer now. Is something not working for you?

Comment: what i get is ` channelrows
-----------
 hard      
 hard      
 hard      
 hard     `

Comment: @KingVince See my edit. For me it works like you wanted.. Please check the content of your input file `D:\Powershell_Project_2\newchannels.csv`. I' think this file has already been overwritten by your earlier attempts.

Comment: when i execute $channelrows i  get only  `Hard` like my output in my code (its the same)

Comment: @KingVince No, your input file is definitively already overwritten and is not what you think it is. Create it new and then run the code.

Comment: @KingVince your code and your input csv file do not match up. Your code assumes you have values `work`,`play` in your file. Yet you show your input file contains `hard`,`hard`. Which is it?

Comment: Can you say what the -f stands for?

Comment: @KingVince `-f` is the [Format operator](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7855.powershell-using-the-f-format-operator.aspx). It fills in the numeric placeholder(s) in the form of `{0}`, `{1}` etc. in a template string. In this case, the template string is `'{0} hard'` and the `{0}` placeholder is replaced with whatever is in `$_.channelrows`